# How to compare complex data type columns in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a `test` table in **hive** with below schema. I want to select all the ids where a and b are equal, how to do that? 
is there any built-in feature exist in hive which supports map datatype comparison?

**Table DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE test(id string,
a map<int,string>,
b map<int,string>)
```

The below sql throws error since equal operator only supports primitive types:

```
select id from test where a=b;
```

> Argument type mismatch 'a': The 1st argument of EQUAL  is expected to
>   a primitive type, but map is found

---

Note: I am able to achieve this using my own UDF, but I am looking if hive provide any inbuilt feature to support such operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id from test where a in (b);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. could you please explain how hive `a in (b)` internally translate?

Comment: I don't get the question. This is basically not different from `x in (1,2,3)`